# Keep getting error: release version 17 not supported Language level is invalid or missing in pom.xml. Current project JDK is 16

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml

The terminal displays that I need to specify the language level in my project but when I do still it show's the same error. Here's my Pom.xml:

```
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
```

I'm trying to run my Spring application but keep getting this error. What to do next?

Comment: If your current project JDK is 16 then you can't compile Java 17 code. You need Java 17 or higher as your project JDK

Comment: I guess that "Current project JDK is 16" means that you have Java 16 installed and that `JAVA_HOME` points to it.  Correct?  If so, Jeroen's comment is spot on.  Install and configure Java 17.  A Java 16 compiler cannot generate code for target version 17.

Comment: Could also be an IDE configuration issue, where the IDE is only aware of JDK 16 even if 17 is installed.

Comment: The OP hasn't mentioned an IDE, but yea that's a possibility.  Without some clear information we can only guess.